# Why do I get a 'breaks not unique' error in my R code?

Tags: r, cut, dplyr

I'm newer to R, so this may be a silly mistake. I'm trying to use the cut function, but I keep getting the same error. Error is:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Calls_bucket`.
x 'breaks' are not unique
i Input `Calls_bucket` is `cut(...)
```

Here's my code (I've tried many different variations. Here are two most recent):

```
m3 <- m2 %>%
  mutate(Calls_bucket=cut(Calls_per_Hour,c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,max(Calls_per_Hour, na.rm=T)),
                         labels=c("0-2","2-4","4-6","6-8","8-10","10-12","12-14","14-16","16-18","18-20",">20")))

m3 <- m2 %>%
  mutate(Calls_bucket=cut(Calls_per_Hour,breaks=c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,max(Calls_per_Hour, na.rm=T)),labels=c("0-2","2-4","4-6","6-8","8-10","10-12","12-14","14-16","16-18","18-20",">20")))
```

I can get it to work if I simply pick the number of breaks, but I want to define them specifically. this code works, for example:

```
m3 <- m2 %>%
  mutate(Calls_bucket=cut(Calls_per_Hour,12))
```

thanks in advance. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `max(Calls_per_Hour, na.rm=T)`? Is it equal to one of your existing breaks? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: instead of `max` use `Inf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While defining the breaks, use `unique()` if you are using `max(Calls_per_Hour)`.
This worked for me

```
m3 <- m2 %>%
    mutate(Calls_bucket=cut(Calls_per_Hour,unique(c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,max(Calls_per_Hour,na.rm=TRUE))),
                            labels=c("0-2","2-4","4-6","6-8","8-10","10-12","12-14","14-16","16-18","18-20",">20"),include.lowest = T))
```

- `unique()` ensures a unique vector of cuts i.e. if `max(Calls_per_Hour)` is equal to a value from your given vector, the cuts remain unique.
- Since you are using 0 to start your labels, you should also include 0 in your cuts.
- Setting `include.lowest=TRUE` ensures that the lowest value encountered is assigned a label.

Comment: Thanks Hasan. This worked! Really appreciate the help, and also the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I included 0 as the first cut. And specified `include.lowest = TRUE`.Therefore every 0 gets included in the first category. By setting include.lowest to FALSE (which is the default) 0 will be transformed to NA.

```
m2 <- data.frame(Calls_per_Hour = 0:25)

m3 <- m2 %>%
  mutate(Calls_bucket=cut(Calls_per_Hour,c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20, Inf),
                          labels=c("0-2","2-4","4-6","6-8","8-10","10-12","12-14","14-16","16-18","18-20",">20"),
                          include.lowest = TRUE))
```

One annotation. In your example the labels are not clear. If I read 0-2 and 2-4 I wouldn't know where to include the 2. So in your actual code you may set the labels unambiguously (0-2, 3-4).